# Can i reuse a for loop for multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

I would like to reuse a for loop which loops over a querySelectorAll variable I have named 'allRooms' I'm just not to sure how to. I want to be able to play around with adding/removing classes on the elements in the loop. In my code below i have used the same for loop twice as you will see although its executing different things its still looping over the same 'allRooms' variable which is what I want to avoid doing. Appreciate any help, I'm still learning javascript.
This is the effect im using the javascript for
https://iamrufus.github.io/

```js
(function() {
  let roomsWrap = document.querySelector('.rooms__wrap');
  let roomImg = document.querySelectorAll('.rooms__img');
  let allRooms = document.querySelectorAll('.rooms__type');
  let roomType;

  roomsWrap.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    reset();
    if (e.target.classList.contains('rooms__type')) {
      roomType = e.target.dataset.room;
      roomImg[roomType].classList.add('active');
      e.target.classList.add('active');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < allRooms.length; i++) {
      allRooms[i].classList.add('hide');
      e.target.classList.remove('hide');
    }
  });

  roomsWrap.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    reset();
  });

  function reset() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allRooms.length; i++) {
      allRooms[i].classList.remove('active', 'hide');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < roomImg.length; i++) {
      roomImg[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<section class="section rooms">
  <div class="rooms__wrap">
    <div class="rooms__img__wrap">
      <div class="rooms__img rooms__img--traditional"></div>
      <div class="rooms__img rooms__img--grande"></div>
      <div class="rooms__img rooms__img--deluxe"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rooms__type__wrap">
      <div class="rooms__type rooms__type--traditional" data-room="0"></div>
      <span class="rooms__type__name">Traditional Suite</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rooms__type__wrap">
      <div class="rooms__type rooms__type--grande" data-room="1"></div>
      <span class="rooms__type__name">Grande Suite</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rooms__type__wrap">
      <div class="rooms__type rooms__type--deluxe" data-room="2"></div>
      <span class="rooms__type__name">Deluxe Suite</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @" its still looping over the same 'allRooms' variable" - I don't see it. One `for` iterates through `allRooms`, another one iterates through `roomImg`.

Comment: Maybe you need to rephrase your question - I can't see a problem. Your two allRooms related for-loops do things at a different time (mouseOver/mouseLeave), that's why you have to have two.

Comment: @mbojko In the mouseover function there is a for loop that loops over allRooms as well as the one in the function 'reset' although they are doing different things i just wondered if there was a way to use the for loop just once and then pass it to other functions and have it do different things. Hope that makes sense. Everything in this IIFE works fine dont get me wrong i just wondered if there was a better more cleaner way of doing it

Comment: You are repeating this line over and over
`e.target.classList.remove('hide');` If you have a more clever reset then just use that

Comment: @mplungjan I have only used that line once? or are you refereeing to e.target?

Comment: @mplungjan good solution, but there r some doubts about logic of script at all. What does a `.hide` style consist of? if smth like `display: none` then after `allRooms[i].classList.add('hide')` there will be nothing to be over for mouse :)

Comment: @Banzay, the solution is great as for the hide class its sets opacity to the given elements as its used to transition images with a higher z-index with an opacity of 0 over the top of another image with a lower z-index that currently has an opacity of 1 thats all. it would be easier to show the effect rather than try to explain it :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it but you could wrap the for-loop inside a parameter-driven function, which does different things based on this parameter.

Something like:

```
function doAllRooms(param, e) {

  for (var i = 0; i < allRooms.length; i++) {
    if (param == 1) {
      allRooms[i].classList.add('hide');
      e.target.classList.remove('hide');
    }
    if (param == 2) {
      allRooms[i].classList.remove('active', 'hide');
    }
  }
}


roomsWrap.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  doAllRooms(1, e);
});

function reset() {
  doAllRooms(2);
}
```

Comment: `e.target.classList.remove('hide');` does not belong in a loop

Comment: Outch you're right. Didn't see he was using the event oject. Fixed by adding it as an additional parameter.